# node.js ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING TypeError: Module tsconfig.json needs an import assertion of type "json"

Tags: node.js, json, typescript2.0, nodejs-server, tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules", 
        "build"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "build/",
        "plugins": [
            {
                "name": "@rollup/plugin-typescript"
            },
            {
                "name": "@rollup/plugin-json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

bumps into the following build error:

```
[!] TypeError: Module "file:///usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/tsconfig.json" needs an import assertion of type "json"
TypeError [ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING]: Module "file:///usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/tsconfig.json" needs an import assertion of type "json"
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at validateAssertions (node:internal/modules/esm/assert:82:15)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:84:3)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:164:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:603:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:459:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:478:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:436:34)
    at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:21)
```

I have set `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in top-level `tsconfig.json`